# Python : How to set id of button

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am using `python-2.7` and `kivy-1.9.0`. Can someone tell me how to set `id` of button?
I am trying to set id`test` of button using this code.

```
btn1 = Button(text="Close",id="test")
```

But it gives error `'Alert' object has no attribute 'test'`

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Window.size = (500, 150)


class Alert(Popup):

    def __init__(self, title, text):
        super(Alert, self).__init__()

        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=(5))
        box.add_widget(Label(text=text))
        btn1 = Button(text="Close",id="test")
        box.add_widget(btn1)

        self.title = title
        self.title_size = 30
        self.title_align = 'center'
        self.content = box
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.size = (300, 200)
        self.auto_dismiss = False

        self.open()
        self.test.background_color = [0, 0, 1, 0.5]


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        Alert(title='yeah!', text='inputs are invalid')
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Define Button id

You have the correct way of assinging an *id* to button in Python script.

```
btn1 = Button(text="Close") 
self.ids['test'] = btn1
```

## *Note*

*The **id** declared in **Python script** is different from **ids** defined in **kv file**.*

## Error

The error that you have encountered is not because the button's id is not set correctly. The keyword ***self*** references the “current widget instance” i.e. Alert/Popup and it does not an attribute *test*.

```
   File ".../main.py", line 33, in __init__
     self.test.background_color = [0, 0, 1, 0.5]
 AttributeError: 'Alert' object has no attribute 'test'
```

## Solution

When the button was defined, it was assigned to an object ***btn1***. Therefore, if you want to change the button's background colour, use

```
btn1.background_color or sef.ids.test.background_colour or self.ids['test'].background_color
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Window.size = (500, 150)


class Alert(Popup):

    def __init__(self, title, text):
        super(Alert, self).__init__()

        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=(5))
        box.add_widget(Label(text=text))
        btn1 = Button(text="Close")
        self.ids['test'] = btn1
        box.add_widget(btn1)

        self.title = title
        self.title_size = 30
        self.title_align = 'center'
        self.content = box
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.size = (300, 200)
        self.auto_dismiss = False

        self.open()
        self.ids.test.background_color = [0, 0, 1, 0.5]


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        Alert(title='yeah!', text='inputs are invalid')
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: The example does not work anymore, I get error `TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)` exactly when defining button id `btn1 = Button(text="Close", id="test")`.

Comment: @mmj: Coding Kivy 'id' in python has been deprecated. Please check updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for id to use button in later cases you can use it in either way just do,

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder`enter code here`
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Window.size = (500, 150)


class Alert(Popup):
    btn1 = Button(text="Close") 
    def __init__(self, title,btn1, text):
        super(Alert, self).__init__()
        self.btn1 = btn1
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=(5))
        box.add_widget(Label(text=text))
        box.add_widget(self.btn1)

        self.title = title
        self.title_size = 30
        self.title_align = 'center'
        self.content = box
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.size = (300, 200)
        self.auto_dismiss = False

        self.open()
        self.test.background_color = [0, 0, 1, 0.5]


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        change_button = Button(text="Close")
        Alert(title='yeah!',btn1=change_button, text='inputs are invalid')
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```